# Contact Form 7 не отображает уведомления при отправке письма

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form7

Возникла проблема с показом уведомлений об успешной отправке формы.
Написал кастомный обработчик wpcf7_before_send_mail.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_start_function' );
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_start_function($cf7) {
$log = "info.log";
$FORMID = 0000;
$SECRET = "some secret key";

// если форма на главной и секретный ключ не заполнен
if (($cf7->id === $FORMID) && ($_POST['secret'] !== $SECRET)) {
    // меняем адрес на несуществующий
    $mail=$cf7->prop('mail');
    if($mail){
        $mail['recipient']="fail@mail.com";
        $cf7->set_properties(array('mail'=>$mail));

        $info = $cf7->id . '///' . $_POST['secret'] . '///' . $cf7->prop('mail')['recipient'];
        error_log($info, 3, $log);
    }
}
return true;
}
```

При несоответствии или отсутствии ключа отправляем письмо на несуществующий адрес. Если ключ совпадает, то отправляем по указанному адресу.

После сабмита письмо на почту приходит (при корректном ключе, конечно). Но не отображается уведомление о успешной отправке. При этом, если какое-то поле заполнено некорректно и отправка не осуществлялась, уведомления показываются.

В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: При сабмите формы появляется скрытый блок ajax-error с ошибкой

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Где находится файл для исправления? Такая же проблема(

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в ($cf7->id === $FORMID).  Заменил его на ($cf7->id() === $FORMID)  и все гуд.